# Task is to export excel data to MySQL and display graphs.!

Tags: python, mysql, angularjs, django, excel-formula

Excel workbook needs to be exported to MySQL and display graphs. Few columns are dependent (with the formula on other columns) on other so every time user performs any CRUD operation simultaneously other dependent columns needs to be updated and the graphs as well.

I am using Python, Django, MySQL, and angularJS.

Is this possible? Any ideas?..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following steps can help you:

1 - open your excel file, and export as .csv

2 - import this .csv file into your MySQL table via SIDU or similar tools

3 - Use SIDU to produce graphs based on your need: eg

[image]

Topnew SIDU uses Topnew SVG Chart plug-in to produce bar chart, line chart, pie chart according to your SQLs

For more info, visit topnew.net/sidu